# Linking an external css file doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to link my local bootstrap, and style file to my html file, but none of them works.

Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link type="text/css" ref="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link type="text/css" ref="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-tops">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

My css files are  located in a folder called css.
I got these files there:

[image: Files in the /css directory]

The htdocs folder I have this:

[image: htdocs folder where the css folder is located]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUST TRY THIS ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test page</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-tops">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

These Codes are Wrong ---

```
 <link type="text/css" ref="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link type="text/css" ref="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

These are Correct ---

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>
```

Comment: Actually you are using the wrong codes to link external css files.

Comment: It would be better to *explain what is wrong* about the wrong lines.